# iterate SQL query to 30 days timeframe and count

Tags: sql

Currently, I have created a count based on a condition and populated 24 hours, 7 days and 30 days data by doing something like this. In the end I would like to create a time series to see how the number changes from day 1 til day 30

This is the code I am currently using:

```
select 
   title,
   item_name,
   category,
   sum(case when (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time)) <= 86400 then 1 else 0 end) day1
   sum(case when (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time)) <= 604800 then 1 else 0 end) day7
   sum(case when (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time)) <= 2592000 then 1 else 0 end) day30
from table1
```

I'm brining `first_seen_video_time` and `subscription_purchase_time` from two different CTEs.

86400 is 24 hours, 604800 is 7 days and 2592000 is 30 days.

How can I get these calculated values for all 30 days without having to hardcode them like this?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the values for different time intervals (24 hours, 7 days, 30 days) dynamically without hard coding the intervals, you can use a combination of sub-queries and conditional aggregation.

```
WITH DateIntervals AS (
    SELECT 
        86400 AS interval_1_day,
        604800 AS interval_7_days,
        2592000 AS interval_30_days
)
SELECT 
    title,
    item_name,
    category,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time) <= di.interval_1_day THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time) <= di.interval_7_days THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (first_seen_video_time - subscription_purchase_time) <= di.interval_30_days THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day30
FROM 
    table1
CROSS JOIN 
    DateIntervals di
GROUP BY 
    title, item_name, category;
```

i just create a common table expression (CTE) called DateIntervals to hold the interval values for 1 day, 7 days, and 30 days.